# Sencha Touch 2: Populating one DataView using multiple stores

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, touch, store

I realise this may sound silly, so hopefully this doesn't come across as being too stupid. I'm wanting to use multiple stores to populate one DataView, or other item that I can apply an itemTpl to. I have a basic idea that I'm wanting to implement:

- I have a store of Users and Items, users can buy items.
- Every user has an associated balance which dictates what items they can purchase.

I want to be able to present a list of items that can be purchased (regardless of whether a user has enough money in their account). Any items that a user can't afford should be greyed out (but still visible).

As you can see from the above pictures, the first user can see all items without any being greyed out (as they have enough balance), however the second user doesn't have enough money available to purchase the armour. Is there any way to grab the information from the two separate stores (ItemStore and UserStore) to list all items, but grey out items that a user doesn't have enough for.

Below is my code:

**(DataView) ItemSelectionScreen:**

```
Ext.define("touchstore.view.purchase.ItemSelectionScreen", {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    xtype: 'item-selection',

    config: {
        store: 'ItemStore',
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<tpl for=".">',
                '<div class="item {canAfford}">', //canAfford should be that the users balance is greater than the price of the item
                    '<h1>{itemName}</h1>',
                    '<span>{description}</span><br />',
                    '<div class="cost"><strong>Cost: {cost}</strong></div>',
                '</div>',
            '</tpl>')
    }
});
```

**ItemModel:**

```
Ext.define('touchstore.model.ItemModel', {    
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'itemName', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'description', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'cost', type: 'int' }
        ]
    }
});
```

**ItemStore:**

```
Ext.define("touchstore.store.ItemStore", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'touchstore.model.ItemModel',
        data: [
            { itemName: 'Sword', description: 'Battle your enemies fiercely with this beautiful, yet deadly sword.', cost: 500 },
            { itemName: 'Armour', description: 'Defend yourself from attacks with this beautifully crafted piece of armour.', cost: 1400 },
            { itemName: 'Leather Boots', description: 'Run faster with these lightweight yet stylish boots.', cost: 400 }
        ]
    }
});
```

**UserModel:**

```
Ext.define("touchstore.model.UserModel", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'username', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'balance', type: 'int' }
        ]
    }
});
```

**UserStore:**

```
Ext.define("touchstore.store.UserStore", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model: 'touchstore.model.UserModel',
        data: [
            { username: 'steve.smith', balance: 2000 },
            { username: 'robert.junior', balance: 500 }
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only one user is active at a time you don't need to create another store, you could display all items from the ItemStore and just calculate {canAfford} based on the currently active user and the item price.

You can use the last parameter of XTemplate to pass an object with a method that can calculate canAfford. Roughly that:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="item {[this.canAfford(values)]}">', //canAfford should be that the users balance is greater than the price of the item
                '<h1>{itemName}</h1>',
                '<span>{description}</span><br />',
                '<div class="cost"><strong>Cost: {cost}</strong></div>',
            '</div>',
        '</tpl>',
        {
            canAfford: function(item) {
                return item.get('cost') <= CURRENT_USER.get('balance') 
                    ? 'CLASS-FOR-CAN-AFFORD' : 'CLASS-FOR-CANNOT-AFFORD';
            }
        })
```

CURRENT_USER is a reference to the currently active user on the system. Commonly, this will come from the login sub-system. Assuming you implemented a LoginController with an getActiveUser method that returns the currently logged user, it could be something like this (Ext JS):

```
touchstore.getApplication().getController('LoginController').getActiveUser()
```

If using Sencha Touch it would be:

```
touchstore.app.getController('LoginController').getActiveUser()
```

**Edit:**

Another option is to use a configuration in the view to pass the current user. The relevant changes in your view:

```
Ext.define("touchstore.view.purchase.ItemSelectionScreen", {
    ...

    config: {
        currentUser: null,

        // Empty template so there will be no errors. 
        // The real template is configured in the initialize method.
        itemTpl: '',
        ...
    },
    ...
    updateCurrentUser: function(newUser) {
       this.refresh();
    },

    // Setup the template in the initialize method. The initConfig is
    // probably better for this, but I could not test it.
    initialize: function() {
        var me = this;
        // The template is configured here so it can access me.getCurrentUser().
        me.setItemTpl(new Ext.XTemplate(...));
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

If your controller does not instantiate the view, it could initialize this value on the initialize event for the view and/or whenever the current user changes.

Comment: Thanks @RicardoMachado. As the DataView is essentially a part of the view layer it wouldn't have access to the application, and therefore won't have access to the 'getController' function. Is there any recommended way to get around this issue?

Also, if I were wanting to add a feature such as an Admin Panel, can you recommend how to do this? Essentially an admin could type in a username, and see what items they may purchase (in the same format as before - greyed out for expensive items). Would this be possible with the username essentially changing on the fly? Thanks again.

Comment: One option would be to use a configuration in the view. This would not only keep things separated (model, view and controller layers) but would also allow changing the user on the fly (just change the configuration). I updated the code with this option.

Comment: Thanks again @RicardoMachado. This would achieve what I'm looking for, in theory. Unfortunately the config object of the XTemplate constructor doesn't appear to get the correct scope, and therefore couldn't call the 'this.getCurrentUser()' function. Again, this is what I'm essentially looking to do.

Comment: You can create the template inside the code of the class, so you can have access to the "this" instance. I updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure will work but try this and let me know.

```
Ext.define("touchstore.view.purchase.ItemSelectionScreen", {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
xtype: 'item-selection',

config: {
    store: [ItemStore,UserStore],
    itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<tpl if="{balance} &gt; {cost}"',
                '<div>',
                    '<h1>{itemName}</h1>',
                    '<span>{description}</span><br />',
                    '<div class="cost"><strong>Cost: {cost}</strong></div>',
                '</div>',
             '</tpl>',
        '</tpl>')
}
});
```